# Two "not"s in one sentence

Tags: multiple-negation

> “Universal history. The history of what man has accomplished" in this world, is at bottom the History of the Great Men who have worked here," wrote the Victorian sage Thomas Carlyle. **Well, not any more it is not.**

It is copied from a test article. Does "not any more it is not" make sense to you? I got the translated version, which suggests the meaning is: "It is not the case anymore." Is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The translation is correct, but misses some of the style of the English.

This sentence is much more conversational than the written style of the previous parts.  It is as if the author is speaking directly to you.  It starts with "Well" (a conversational linking word)

Then there is the phrase "not any more"  This is a sentence fragment, which we understand to mean "It is not (the case) anymore". The sentence could have ended there, but the author reduplicates the sentence.  "It's not"  That also means "It's not (the case)"

This is an idiom, a fixed phrase that gets some use eg:

> Brennan: I'm throwing out my book.
> Booth: It's still on your hard drive, right?
> Brennan: No, not any more it's not.
> Booth: You erased it?

It is typically spoken, so the only thing I find slightly odd is that the "it is" would normally be contracted to "it's".